# ADO.NET DataTable does not allow null column in multi-column foreign key

Tags: c#, datatable, ado.net, dataset

I have a parent-child relationship between two SQL Server tables, with a multi-column foreign key. Using straight T-SQL, I am able to insert rows in the child table where some of the foreign key columns are `null`, as expected.

However, if I attempt to do this using `DataSet` and `DataTable`, I get an `InvalidConstraintException` (see the example below). I only encounter this problem for multi-part keys; a row with a single null foreign key column can be inserted without `InvalidConstraintException`.

I have been unable to find any information on this situation in the ADO.NET context.

Questions:

- Am I doing something wrong?
- Can anyone suggest a workaround? My own best ideas:

  - Disable enforcement of constraints
  - Insert a magic value, e.g. `-1`, instead of `null` in the datatable, and then write these as `null` to the database
  - Actually write the magic value to the database; but in my case, this would approximately double the number of rows in the parent table.

Example T-SQL code (runs without error, as expected):

```
CREATE TABLE [P](
    [P1] [int] NOT NULL,
    [P2] [int] NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY ([P1], [P2])
)

CREATE TABLE [C](
    [C1] [int] NOT NULL,
    [P1] [int] NOT NULL,
    [P2] [int] NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY ([C1] ASC)
)
ALTER TABLE [C] ADD CONSTRAINT [FK_C_P]
FOREIGN KEY([P1], [P2]) REFERENCES [dbo].[P] ([P1], [P2])

INSERT C (C1, P1, P2) VALUES (1, 1, NULL)
```

Example C# code (exception thrown from the last line):

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var p = new DataTable("P");
    var pp1 = new DataColumn("P1", typeof(int));
    var pp2 = new DataColumn("P2", typeof(int));
    p.Columns.AddRange(new[] { pp1, pp2 });
    p.PrimaryKey = new[] { pp1, pp2 };
    var c = new DataTable("C");
    var cc1 = new DataColumn("C1", typeof(int));
    var cp1 = new DataColumn("P1", typeof(int));
    var cp2 = new DataColumn("P2", typeof(int));
    c.Columns.AddRange(new[] { cc1, cp1, cp2 });
    c.PrimaryKey = new[] { cc1 };
    c.Constraints.Add(new ForeignKeyConstraint(new[] { pp1, pp2 }, new[] { cp1, cp2 }));
    var s = new DataSet() { EnforceConstraints = true };
    s.Tables.AddRange(new[] { p, c });

    // the following throws InvalidConstraintException
    c.Rows.Add(1, 1, null);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you try using

```
//nullable  int?
```

instead of

```
int
```

in the type of your keys? Im not familiar with ADO.NET, but i had a similar problem with the Entity Framework , and this solved my problem.

Comment: I tried this, but it does not work. ADO.NET is pre-2.0, and nullable types are not supported (you get an exception from the DataColumn constructor).

Answer (score 0):

1. In any database if you have a schema with tables as a condition not null, you unable to make changes.
2. But NULL value you can utilize for the foreign key.
3. Try to use sql command instead of data table it makes you easier.
4. [Microsoft sql command](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9s8ekk5c(v=vs.110).aspx)
5. For example

[basic sql command usage](http://www.dotnetperls.com/sqlcommand)

Answer (score 0):

As the error message says when running the program, *"ForeignKeyConstraint Constraint2 requires the child key values (1, ) to exist in the parent table."* then you need to have a row with those values in `p`. To do that, you must specify that `pp2` allows `DBNull` values, and add the row to `p`. That is after

```
p.PrimaryKey = new[] { pp1, pp2 };
```

add

```
pp2.AllowDBNull = true;
```

and before

```
c.Rows.Add(1, 1, null);
```

add

```
p.Rows.Add(1, null);
```

This brings the complete example, as you posted, to the following:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var p = new DataTable("P");
    var pp1 = new DataColumn("P1", typeof(int));
    var pp2 = new DataColumn("P2", typeof(int));
    pp2.DefaultValue = DBNull.Value;
    p.Columns.AddRange(new[] { pp1, pp2 });
    p.PrimaryKey = new[] { pp1, pp2 };
    pp2.AllowDBNull = true;
    var c = new DataTable("C");
    var cc1 = new DataColumn("C1", typeof(int));
    var cp1 = new DataColumn("P1", typeof(int));
    var cp2 = new DataColumn("P2", typeof(int));
    c.Columns.AddRange(new[] { cc1, cp1, cp2 });
    c.PrimaryKey = new[] { cc1 };
    c.Constraints.Add(new ForeignKeyConstraint(new[] { pp1, pp2 }, new[] { cp1, cp2 }));
    var s = new DataSet() { EnforceConstraints = true };
    s.Tables.AddRange(new[] { p, c });

    // the following no longer throws InvalidConstraintException
    p.Rows.Add(1, null);
    c.Rows.Add(1, 1, null);
}
```

**Edit:** As have been clarified in the question, the wish is to avoid having the parent row. ADO.NET does not allow that. If you change `c.Rows.Add(1, 1, null)` to `c.Rows.Add(1, null, null)`, it will not throw `InvalidConstraintException` anymore. That is, it requires all values to either be null (instead of one or more), or the value to be present in the parent table.

I would probably consider temporarily adding the parent rows to keep constraint checking and then when you're ready to insert to the database, disable constraint checking and remove the unnecessary rows from the parent table.

Comment: Yes, this would work. But in T-SQL I do not need the "null rows" in the parent table, and I would rather avoid inserting these rows (in my case, the total row count would approximately double if I inserted them). I have amended my question with a working T-SQL example.